# I need information about a vintage pulse generator model 521

Tags: power-supply

I found a very old pulse generator which simply says Model 521, Digital Electronics, Westbury L.I. on it.

I need to know how to determine what voltage it is putting out.

It will easily light up most LEDs that I attach to it via wires and pulse them perfecly, but I could very well burn them out if I don't know how much voltage/amps the generator is feeding them. It can cycle from 50 to 500 KC no problem, but when I try to use a multimeter in series or in parallel to determine its voltage output, the multimeter goes crazy. I imagine because the cycling that the generator is creating confuses the heck out of it.

I've tried online to find a user or specification manual for it but no luck.

Here's a [youtube link to the only info that I found on the internet.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEf7b1xN02U)

Comment: That company made computers and test equipment in the 1960s...Here is a listing from an old directory....Digital Electronics Inc., 2200 Shames Drive, Westbury, N.Y. / ED 3-2115 / *C 63...[ General purpose computers, training computers,(- data conversion equipment, computer test equipment, magnetic tape systems / RMa Ss (25) Ser (1961) DIc   - it will take you a while, but I think you should do what you can to find as much as possible about them and that product first before going too far.  Any chance of a few pictures??

Comment: Model 522  Pulser from them https://worldradiohistory.com/Archive-Electronics/60s/63/Electronics-1963-07-19.pdf on page 115 - does yours look like that? Getting closer (I love this early electronics history).

Comment: Try using an oscilloscope instead of a multimeter?

Comment: You could also make a simple peak detector circuit. Diode, capacitor. Done. Now measure the capacitor voltage.

Comment: Great info, will make a peak detector as suggested. Also here's a link to the only youtube video I found.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEf7b1xN02U